# Pass Powershell Variables to MySQL

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am using SimplySQL (https://github.com/mithrandyr/SimplySql) to access MySQL from Powershell.  I have a script which gets me yesterday's sunrise and sunset times.  What I am attempting to do next is pass those variables into the mysql script to pull a corresponding column of values from between those hours.  However, I am missing something.

Sunrise/Sunset:

```
$yesDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
$daylight = (Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=35.608237&lng=-78.647497&formatted=0&date=$esDate").results
$sunrise  = ($daylight.Sunrise | Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss")
$sunset   = ($daylight.Sunset | Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss")
```

MySQL query:

```
CD "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"
Open-MySqlConnection -UserName xxxxxxx -Password -Database xxxxxxxx
Invoke-SqlQuery -Query "select LogDateTime, UVindex from `monthly_new` where LogDateTime between (curdate()) - interval 1 day and (curdate())"
Close-SqlConnection
```

Right now, running each separately sets the variables, and returns all values from 12am to 11:59pm yesterday.  But if I try to integrate the $sunrise and $sunset variables into the mysql query, it has no idea what is going on.  It could be just a simple syntax issue, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to avoid inserting parameters into SQL query text.

Take `MySQL .Net connector` from Oracle (actually you need only `MySql.Data.dll` file from whole installation)

Then for SELECT's use DataAdapter. It accepts connection string and SQL command.
ConnectionString may contain parameters.
Then add parameters with values.
Then create DataSet and Fill it using adapter. 
Work with `dataset.tables[0]` as with array of objects with properties.

Something like that, I have no MySQL now to test.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.21\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll"

$sqlCommandSelect = 'select LogDateTime, UVindex from `monthly_new` where LogDateTime between @param1 and @param2'
$sqlConnString = 'server=server;user=user;database=db;password=*****;"'

$dataAdapter = [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter]::new($sqlCommandSelect, $sqlConnString)
$dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue('@param1', [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1))
$dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue('@param2', [DateTime]::Today)

$dataSet = [System.Data.DataSet]::new()
$numRecords = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
foreach ($row in $dataSet.Tables[0])
{
    Write-Host "$($row.LogDateTime)`t$($row.UVindex)"
}

$dataSet.Dispose()
$dataAdapter.Dispose()
```

---

Alternatively, you can directly write variables to the SQL Query, but you need to write it in format that MySQL accepts. I suppose this is `o` format:

```
$query = "select ...  '($($date1.ToString('o')))' and '($($date2.ToString('o')))'"
```

Something like that, I'm not sure about quotes around ($($....))

Comment: Interesting...so I'd still be using my script to calculate sunrise and sunset and then set those as @param1 and 2?